# How can I hover over an image in order to make a second image appear?

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

I recently started learning jquery and I want to ask the following.

Let's say I want to do this http://jsfiddle.net/gnVud/172/ .

Basicly when I hover over the main image I want a second image to appear with the zoom icon. What I did is working but I am 100% sure it's not the right way to do it. So

1) Right now I am doing

```
zoom.on('mouseenter',function() {
    image.stop(true,true).fadeTo(100,1);
});
zoom.on('mouseleave',function() {
    image.stop(true,true).fadeTo(100,0.5);
});
```

so when it's over the zoom image the main image acts like the hover is outside of it. If I put the mousenter event on the main image then it will flicker when I hover over the zoom. So what's the right way to do it? What I wrote is working but I am pretty sure it must be a much better way to do it.

2) Right now I am using find two times. One on mouseenter one on mouseeleave. Is there a way to make them global?

3) Right now I have an event on the main div and I use a selector at the end. Is this better than having `$('.cont').on` ? Is it the same?

Comment: what you have done is exactly the way to do it. You could also wrap the image in it's own wrapping element and call the hover events on the wrapper

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but what will be the benefit of adding an extra div?

Comment: no benefit really...sometimes easier to keep modules self contained is all